# How to prevent deadlock in the Oracle database + Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am using oracle database with Java/Hibernate, with following table:

```
Id| Status |....
1  PENDING
2  COMPLETED
```

From two different transactions, the following queries are executed:

```
1)select particular record, then update it
for(select some record from table){
  update record status to COMPLETED
  session.flush()
}
2) update records bunch
update table set status = 'PENDING' where....
```

(queries could be executed in any order so #1 could occurs before #2 and and vice versa)

As the result I have query 2) executed forever, so I think it is deadlock situation. Oracle Enterprise Manager shows that query 2) waits for TX lock.

How can I handle this situation?

I read about `select ... for update` construction(`lockmode.upgrade` in Hibernate), but in this case I think it will lock the entire table, so execution time will increase.

Comment: A deadlock is very different from a blocking lock.  What you're describing appears to be a blocking lock.  Is there some predicate in your `for`?  Or are you selecting every row from the table?

Comment: Can you clarify the timing of both transactions?  Do the operations of transaction #1 occur before the 2nd one starts?  When the 2nd one starts, has the first committed the changes?  If you're 2nd transaction starts on a different connection before the 1st has committed, of course it's going to lock.

Comment: @JustinCave i am selecting particular rows(there are some logic), so not every row

Comment: @SamStanojevic timing is random it is two separate background threads. So #1 could occurs before #2 and and vice versa

Comment: OK.  So your `for` loop has a predicate.  And your second transaction's `update` has a predicate.  But they are trying to update the same rows?  It seems odd that you'd have one session updating a row to COMPLETED and another session trying to update that same row to PENDING.  Presumably, only one of those two statuses can be right.  Are you sure that the `SELECT` in transaction #1 should return some of the same rows that the `UPDATE` in transaction #2 is trying to modify?

Comment: @JustinCave no rows are not the same #2 is dealing only with COMPLETED (with some conditions) and #1 updates records with PROPOSED (with some conditions) status. SO no comon rows for both queries.

Comment: If there were no common rows, then there would be no blocking.  If the first transaction was updating a completely different set of rows than the second transaction, there should be no reason for the second transaction to block.  Are you absolutely certain that the two sessions are not trying to update the same row?  What is the full `v$lock` output when the second session is blocked?

Comment: @JustinCave unfortunately I can't check v$lock because this issue happened week ago. But our support team said that #2 query sometimes uses Full scan to update records (because not all columns are indexed) that why theoretically it can lock entire table, am I right?

Comment: Nope.  Even if the second query uses a full scan to access the table, it will only lock those rows that are being updated.  It wouldn't lock any other rows.  If there is really row-lock contention, which seems to be what the question implies but the `v$lock` table might tell a slightly different tale, then the two queries must be trying to update the same row.

Comment: I found doc that says "When a transaction obtains a row lock for a row, the transaction also acquires a table lock for the table in which the row resides. " http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502 . I will check my code tomorrow, but if  the two queries must be trying to update the same row, could select ... for update be usefull here?

Comment: @JustinCave I have checked the code, so queries don't update the same row...strange situation

Comment: Like @JustinCave said, `v$lock` will tell the real story of what is going on here. Your code suggests that if there are no common rows there is no lock to be had. Your support team might not be accurate in saying there is a lock. Reproduce it and query `v$lock` and even check active session history for row lock contention wait statuses.

Comment: @mmmmmpie I have following message from oracle enterprise manager - Waiting for event "enq: TX - row lock contention" in wait class "Application" accounted for 100% of the database time spent in processing the SQL statement with SQL_ID "XXXX". So there are some locks.

Comment: Great. What does v$lock show?

Comment: @mmmmmpie it is from oem history ...Does v$lock stores history data somewhere? Because this happened week ago and not more reproducible.

Comment: Oh I thought you had it reproduced. You will have to wait for the error to recur.

Comment: Doing a `select for update` might be helpful.  It might, on the other hand, turn your blocking lock problem into an actual deadlock problem.   Or it might change which of the two processes block.  If you don't expect that you'd be updating the same row(s) with the two processes, figuring out why you have two processes trying to update the same row to different values would seem like a more productive course than changing your locking scheme.